# Extart jtl files by shell to get some string as variables

Tags: xml, shell

As below,

```
 <httpSample t="488" lt="488" ts="1434602824074" s="true" lb="https://errata-web.app.qa.eng.nay.redhat.com/errata/change_state/20872" rc="302" rm="" tn="" dt="text" by="1271" ng="0" na="0"/>
```

I want to extract the values of "ts" and "t" to do some process only by bash. 
How I can do it?

Comment: sounds like a job for *awk*. you should be able to do it after following a basic tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

```
$var1=<httpSample t="488" lt="488" ts="1434602824074" s="true" lb="https://errata-web.app.qa.eng.nay.redhat.com/errata/change_state/20872" rc="302" rm="" tn="" dt="text" by="1271" ng="0" na="0"/>
```

then use var1

```
$ echo $var1 | tr '=' ' '| cut -d' ' -f 3,7
```

for storing in variable:

```
t=`echo $var1 | tr '=' ' '| cut -d' ' -f 3`
ts=`echo $var1 | tr '=' ' '| cut -d' ' -f 7`
```

now you can see the content by: echo $t

If you dont know the position of t do this:

```
echo $var1 | sed s/t=/#/g | cut -d'#' -f2 | cut -d' ' -f1
```

Comment: Thanks. But In fact, the position of "ts=" and "t=" can be changed with user's setting. We would better not get it value by position.Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @wlin I added an extra line for this situation, take a look please.

Comment: Smart! Thanks dear, It fixed the problem.

Comment: But whether we have a better way. 1 When there is "#" in the file, the scripts will fail. 2 When user's setting is changed and there is 'rt="456"', the scripts still will fail.

Comment: Thanks dear. I also think "awk" even "greo -oP" can work well , but I do not know how them can work. The example "ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2187389" still use the "$2" the position to get the second file value.  We need to search more.

Comment: hope you find your answer :)

Comment: Thanks dear. You have helped me a lot.